# Using a ChannelFactory with Simple Injector

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, simple-injector, channelfactory

I have some integration tests that run by using `ChannelFactory` to create an instance of the service.

My normal WCF Service is setup using [Simple Injector](https://simpleinjector.org), but I can't seem to figure out how to get that to work with my `ChannelFactory` code.

Here is what my test setup code looks like:

```
private readonly IMyService myChannel;

public TestingClient(Binding binding, string serviceUrl)
{
    var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(serviceUrl);

    var myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IMySErvice>(binding, endpointAddress);
    myChannel = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
}
```

When I run my tests it looks like `myChannel.MyServiceOperation();`  But I get an error of:

> The service type provided could not be loaded as a service because it does not have a default (parameter-less) constructor

This is because normally WCF does not support constructors with parameters.  But SimpleInjector fixes that and allows for parameters that it knows how to construct.

Because of this MyService has a constructor that looks like this:

```
public MyService(Validations validations)
{
    this.validations = validations;
}
```

And `Validations` is injected by Simple Injector (see [here for how that is setup without a `ChannelFactory`](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wcfintegration.html))

But since I am setting it up manually with the `ChannelFactory`, I don't know how to get SimpleInjector in the mix (so it can inject the `Validations` object).

**Can anyone tell me how to get Simple Injector to work with a `ChannelFactory`?**

Comment: I'm not sure I get it. Which type do you wish to resolve with Simple Injector?

Comment: @Steven - I updated the question with more details.  It is Validations on the `MyService` object that I am trying to get injected.  And it works fine with a normal WCF service startup.  But I don't know how to do it with a `ChannelFactory`.

Comment: Can you post the all the related exception information? That is exception message, exception types and stack trace of the thrown exception and all its inner exceptions.

Comment: My advice is to make your WCF service a Humble Object, part of the Composition Root, and let it just let it forward the call to a real service that you resolve from the container inside this new Humble Object.